# Unable to open xml file

Tags: php, xmlreader

this is trh code im using

```
  $xmlfile = "Controller\thexmlfile.xml";
  $reader = new XMLReader();
  $reader->open($xmlfile);
```

…and this is the message I get:

> Warning: XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data

I'm using Symfony and the xmlfile is in the same folder as the controller.

Comment: '         $xmlfile = "Controller\ElevesAvecAdresses.xml";
        $reader = new XMLReader();
        $reader->open($xmlfile);
'

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for someone to help you: we can't see where the file is, or what it contains. Have you tried specifying the full path, rather than a relative one?

Comment: yes i tried now, and its still not working, also im developping in symfony and the xml file is on the same folder as the code php document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // $xmlfile = "Controller\\thexmlfile.xml";
   $xmlfile = "Controller/thexmlfile.xml";
   $reader = new XMLReader();
   $reader->open($xmlfile);
```

There is a typo in your path string.

In a string the \t token is changed to a tab character and therefore you can't open the file.

You can use a double backslash to have a literal backslash in the string or use the forward slash (also windows honor this path separator).

I would use the second solution (the one it is not commented in the
excerpt), as it is less error prone (to me, it is a breeze to forgot a slash in a string) and works without modification in windows and linux/unix environments.

**ADDENDUM:**

Splitting the loading and parsing in two different instruction allow to check if something is going wrong with the filesystem or with the xml parsing phase.

```
   // $xmlfile = "Controller\\thexmlfile.xml";
   $xmlfile = "Controller/thexmlfile.xml";
   $xmlContent = file_get_contents($xmlFile);
   // HERE you can test if the content of the file is ok
   $reader = XMLReader::XML($xmlContent);
```

Comment: $xmlfile = "App\\Controller\\data\\ElevesAvecAdresses.xml"; i tried this and it's still not working it's like it doesnt find the file, but the file is there and also im developping in symfony

Comment: Do it works if you use the absolute path of the file? The realtive path you are using can be wrong based on you current directory. You can discover your position in the filessystem with [getcwd function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd)

Comment: i tried with the absolute path and no it doesnt work, is there any other way to read a xml filewsing php in symfony ?

Comment: @AltiBALLA Try to split the process in two phases, first read the file and then put the content into the reader. You will have the chance to test what is going wrong.

Comment: @AltiBALLA From PHP document comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php#120266 it seems you have to use a `file://` protocol to open a file, not just the path. It worth a check (^_-)